# R sf join problem

Tags: r, sf

I have two spatial data sets, one is a census boundary shape file (multipolygon), and the other is a data set of households (points). I want to do a spatial join to see which census boundary each household belongs to. I did a simple spatial join to see where the points are relative to the multipolygon.

```
household_points_csd <- household_points_sf %>%   
  st_join(census_subdivision, join = st_intersects)
```

99% of points lie within a census boundary, but there are some that seem to be just outside any census boundary, and for these households, I am getting a missing value. Based on the data, I know these households "should" lie within some census boundary, but I think they are not intersecting because of the following warning: `st_intersects assumes that the coordinates they are planar`. To overcome this, I want to simply join all of the points that fall outside any census boundary, to the nearest boundary. So the 99% of points that falling with a boundary doesn't need to be changed. I just want to subset the points that fall outside, and join them to the nearest census boundary.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how is it possible that a change of projection results in a change of point-in-polygon relationship? I have seen weird edge cases involving the poles, but for "normal" points & polygons I would expect no change (angles and distances are a different matter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `st_nearest_feature` to get the index of the nearest feature in set Y from each of a set of features in set X.

I'm not sure you can plug this into `st_join` - I tend to always do the intersection/nearest call separately, check that makes sense, and then merge dataframes on ID values if I need to.

Answer (score 0):

Building off Spacedman's answer, you can try the following:

```
library(sf)

# Load polygon and points data set
polygon_data <- st_read("data/polygon.shp")
point_data <- st_read("data/points.shp")
```

`st_intersects` returns a list.  Each item represents a point. If the point is within a polygon, it will contain an index position of that polygon. If not, then its empty. We can determine the length of each list using lengths().  For any point
not intersected by a polygon will have a length of 0, these are the points we are after.

```
length_list <- st_intersects(point_data, polygon_data) |> lengths() 

# Extract the points that are located outside the polygon
points_outside <- point_data[length_list == 0,]
```

Use `st_nearest_feature()` to determine the nearest polygon and append the attribute data from the polygons to the points.

```
closest_feature <- st_nearest_feature(points_outside, polygon_data)

# Add the attribute values from the polygons to the points
points_outside <- polygon_data[closest_feature,] |> st_drop_geometry() |> cbind(points_outside)
```